# Javascript objects and array elements accessing

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am writing code for the drawing chart for support time series data by using VizGrammar JS library.

I am facing an issue with objects and arrays in javascript.

I am getting lots of Arrays,[image: console output]from that I need only first block of arrays only. How can I access that?

```
var data =  [
      {
        ...
        },
        "data": [
          ["test", 3.12 , Hello],
          .....
      ],
      }
    ];

innerDataValues = data[0].data;

console.log(innerDataValues);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you explain a bit more? What happened when you tried `innerDataValues = data[0].data;`?

Comment: the arrays (ex : ["test", 3.12 , Hello] ......... ) gettting assigned to var innerDataValues ;

Comment: So if I understand right, you have array of object. These object have a `data` array and you need them. Am I right?

Comment: yes , issue here is I did not understand the output in console when I code console.log(innerDataValues);

Comment: I guess Kevin's answer might help. Idea is you will have to loop on all such objects and return data in first object. You can use custom for loop or you can look into `array.map` which does similar stuff

Answer (score 0):

```js
$scope.getData = function(data) {
      var innerData = '';
      for (var i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j<data[i].data.length; j++) {

         
            innerData += data[i].steps[j];
          
        }
      }
      return innerData;
    }
```

Here data am getting inside the argument is your Whole data , and the loop with var j is for your innerData . If you want to get particular data inside the innerData means you can put

```js
innerData += data[i].steps[j].Whatever You want;
```

(Instead of $scope you can use 'this' also) Hope it will works .

Comment: may I know how to console it and to check the output please ?

Comment: console.log('this is my innerData',angular.toJson(innerData);

Comment: In where after your $scope.getData = ...     console.log('this is my innerData',angular.toJson(innerData);

Comment: before that return statement you can print, if you want to print out side that method, You can call that method with argument(data) . Then you can print

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain first block of each element by using [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

#### ES6 version

```
var innerDataValues = data.map(element => element.data);
```

#### ES5 version

```
var innerDataValues = date.map(function(el){ return el.data; })
```

**Edit** : that works with this exemple :

```
var data = [{
              "prop" : {
                "val" : 12,
                "eval": 36
              },
              "data": [
                  ["test", 3.12 ,"Hello"],
                  ["toto", 18, "titi"]
              ]
            },
            {
                "prop" : {
                  "val" : 25,
                  "eval": 64
                },
                "data": [
                    ["prod", 3.13 ,"Hi"],
                    ["john", 18, "mike"]
                ]
            }
         ];
var innerDataValues = data.map(element => element.data);
console.log(innerDataValues); //[ [ [ 'test', 3.12, 'Hello' ], [ 'toto', 18, 'titi' ] ],  [ [ 'prod', 3.13, 'Hi' ], [ 'john', 18, 'mike' ] ] ]
```

Comment: Yes I've just fixed above in the code. sorry for having written element **[0]**.data. just delete **[0]**. Thanks for the test.

Comment: Then I got like https://postimg.org/image/bu4wlfkkn/ , Only accessing the first array is enough for me, that's where I am stuking. something like console.log(((innerDataValues[0])[0]).data); and this is the inside of one [Array[45]] https://postimg.org/image/ms7y2dmrl/.

Comment: got it my question ?

Comment: No in fact I don't understand clearly. I advise you to post your input Array or at least part of it (the first two sub-objects) and what you are expecting to obtain. That's the reason why I gave an exemple of input Array in my answer

Comment: please go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38544138/javascript-objects-and-arrays-elements-access , need your help. Thanks in advanced.